# What does rand() do in C?

Tags: c, random

What does rand() do in C?  I don't use C++, just C.
Visual Studio 2012 tells me that its return type is int    __cdecl
And it is part of stdlib.h
It does not take any parameters.
How can I set the range in which it generates (pseudo)random numbers?
Your answers are greatly appreciated

Comment: try [google](http://linux.die.net/man/3/rand)

Comment: I did try google, but I did not find any helpful information.

Comment: [rand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/398ax69y(v=vs.120).aspx)

Comment: So how can I set the range?

Comment: So, it gives you a pseudo-random number. If that's the answer you are looking for, learn how to use google. If not, rephrase your question.

Comment: Please do an effort before posting question here.

Comment: You can't set the range. The range is 0 to MAX_RAND.

Comment: Oops, RAND_MAX. It's a constant defined in <stdlib.h>. The actual value is not specified by the C specification.

Comment: how can I find the actual value then?

Comment: I have the strong feeling you should instantly consult a C book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that there's an actual question: You can't. The range is fixed, and it's defined by the constant `RAND_MAX` if you need to know it (it's `[0 .. RAND_MAX]`)

If you want a different range, you have to arrange that yourself, typically using the *modulo* operator `%` and optionally an offset ... for random numbers between `5` and `9` use

```
int foo = rand() % 5 + 5;
```

I use a helper function like this in the game i recently wrote:

```
int
randomNum(int min, int max)
{
    static int seeded = 0;
    if (!seeded)
    {
        seeded = 1;
        srand((unsigned int)time(0));
    }
    return (rand() % (max-min+1)) + min;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new to c.  So what does [0..RAND_MAX] do?  and how do i find out RAND_MAX from that?  Thanks so much

Comment: `RAND_MAX` is a constant (defined by your implementation of C) declared in `stdlib.h`. that means it can be different for every compiler, but it is typically a large value. In general, just use modulo to transform the range to what you need.

Comment: Oh...I get it now!  Thanks so much!

Comment: Note: If you need *high-quality* random numbers, you need to look elsewhere (probably /dev/urandom on Linux).

Comment: @immibis indeed. `rand()` is not for cryptography, but it's ok for games :)

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the compiler. This wiki article contains a list of them: [linear congruential generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator)

If you need to extend the range of rand(), call it multiple times and merge the outputs:

```
unsigned int r;
    /* ... */
    r  = ((rand()>>4) & 0xff)<< 0;
    r += ((rand()>>4) & 0xff)<< 8;
    r += ((rand()>>4) & 0xff)<<16;
    r += ((rand()>>4) & 0xff)<<24;
```

Example program to show how rand works by comparing the returned value. This works with Microsoft compiles (no mismatch).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
unsigned int seed = 1;
unsigned int rand1, rand2;
unsigned int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        seed = seed*214013 + 2531011;
        rand1 = (seed >> 16) & 0x7fffu;
        rand2 = rand();
        if(rand1 != rand2)
            printf("mismatch %d %d\n", rand1, rand2);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Since only 15 bits of the seed are returned by this version of rand(), then RAND_MAX would be 32767 or hex 0x7fff. As noted in the wiki article, the period is 2^32, this means that seed will cycle through all 4,294,967,296 possible 32 bit values, never repeating until the 4,294,967,296 call to rand(), where seed will have cycled back to 1.

Comment: Wow thanks for being the only person who gave me a respectful answer.  That wiki article, however, does not give me any help.  The library is stdlib.h, on windows.

Comment: Then the line in the wiki article for Visual / Quick C / C++ is used. The internal seed is a 32 bit number, but as shown, bits 30 through 16 of the seed are returned, which is a 15 bit value. The seed is initialized to 1.

Comment: um...sorry im really new to this, what is a seed?  and what does this tell me about RAND_MAX?

Comment: It's a *pseudo random number generator* that means it's not really random. Starting from the same seed, the sequence returned will be the same. That's why you typically use the current time as a seed (or a fixed value for debugging, **iff** you always want the same "random" numbers)